# Updating geoJson within CallbackHandler on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, callback, leaflet

I am having trouble updating a displayed `geoJSON` on a leafletmap.
I am working with `d3` and `leaflet`. The `callbackHandler` receives a new `geoJSON`(`name`) every time the user choses so.

My code looks the following:

```
someCallbackHandler("name", function("newName") {
     var newJson = JSON.parse(newName);
     // then its basically this
     https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/
     ...
 });
```

The first `geoJson` gets displayed. However, whenever the user choses to display another one, the map does not get updated.
What is causing this behaviour?
Since the displayfunction is nested within the `callbackHandler` it should be evoked every time it gets send a new `geoJson`. Or am I missing something?

**edit**

Its hard to post a full example of the code since it has a lot of dependencies...
I narrowed it down to this bit.
What I found out so far is that when the `callbackHandler` kicks in the first time, `console.log(newJson)` gives me an `Object`. When the `callbackHandler` kicks in the second, third, fourth, ... time I get that:
`{crs: {type: "name", properties: ... "FeatureCollection", features: Array}`. When I check the values in the `Object / {crs: {type: ....` I see that they are differently. But the map of them does not change.

That does not seem right?!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, and only examining this extract, I would definitely say the first problem to solve is getting rid of the quotes around your `newName` parameter in the callback function...

It should look like `someCallbackHandler("name", function(newName) {`

Comment: Sorry, thats a typo... Of course its not a string but a variablename.

Comment: Ok, can you post a full example of this somewhere?

Comment: If your callback handler gives you drastically different results depending on run count, then maybe we need to see some of your backend code generating that response. Also...lets see some of your map changing code to see what problems exist in there.